# Why sync button is doing nothing?

Tags: sync

I am using sp 2013. When I go to my mysite and go to the document library I see a sync button in top right corner. When I click on it, it is doing nothing. What does it needs to do?

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it occur only on your account and on all browsers?

Comment: Im using IE11. I tested it on Chrome and have the same issue. It is doing nothing. What do I need to expect? Some popup or the file explorer window?

Comment: You should get a in-browser dialog saying "Sync this library to your device for easy access." and a button "Sync now". Verify site is in Trusted Sites in IE settings and/or it is not blocking JavaScript used to trigger that dialog.

Comment: The site was already added to the trusted sites. I also do not see some js blocker.

Comment: Verify you have OneDrive for Business installed, as it's the one it will anyway use. It missing might make button non-responsive.